# invalid pointer free()

Tags: c

```
ERROR: (gdb)
#0  0x00007ffff7a66067 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff7a67448 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff7aa41b4 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1,
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7b99530 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff7aa998e in malloc_printerr (action=1,
    str=0x7ffff7b95646 "free(): invalid pointer", ptr=<optimized out>)
    at malloc.c:4996
#4  0x00007ffff7aaa696 in _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>,
    have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3840
#5  0x0000000000400bb9 in free_all_filenames_array (all_files=0x605010, len=1)
    at directorio.c:24
#6  0x00000000004028a0 in add_all_directory ()
#7  0x0000000000401967 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe288) at programa.c:30
```

esta es mi función :

```
void free_all_filenames_array(char **all_files, int len){

  int i;


  for (i = 0; i<len; i++){

      if(all_files[i] != NULL){
       free(all_files[i]); // linea 24
       all_files[i] = NULL;
      }
    }

  if(all_files != NULL){
  free(all_files);
  all_files = NULL;
  }
}

int read_all_filenames_array(char *path, char ***all_files, int *error){

  void ** ptr;
  char **nombres = NULL;
  struct dirent *contenido;
  char realPath[PATH_MAX];
  static int num_nombres = 0;


  DIR *dir  = opendir(path);

  if(dir == NULL){
    printf(" ERROR");
    free(path);
    *error = errno;
    closedir(dir);
    return -1;
  }
//   
  realpath(path,realPath);

  while ((contenido = readdir(dir)) != NULL){

  if( contenido->d_type == DT_REG){// si es regular

    ptr = realloc(nombres, (num_nombres + 1) * sizeof(char *));

    if (ptr == NULL){
       printf("ERROR couldnt reallocate the memory");
      *error = errno;
      free_all_filenames_array(nombres,num_nombres);
      closedir(dir);
      return -1;
    }

    nombres = (char **)ptr;

    strcat(realPath,contenido->d_name);
    nombres[num_nombres] = strdup(realPath);

    if(nombres[num_nombres] == NULL){
       free_all_filenames_array(nombres,num_nombres + 1);
       *error = errno;
       closedir(dir);
       return -1;
    }

    num_nombres++;
  }
 }


if (nombres != NULL){
      *all_files = nombres;
     free_all_filenames_array(nombres,num_nombres); // AQUI ME SUELE DAR EL ERROR
     nombres = NULL;
  }
  else printf("Sin ficheros regulares");

  *error = errno;
  closedir(dir);
  return num_nombres;

 }
```

Comment: se necesita más información para poder ayudarte, probablemente estas liberando un puntero que no contiene memoria del heap pero no es posible saberlo con el código que muestras...

Comment: No lo entiendo muy bien. ¿Quieres decir que `nombres` en un array de `char *`? ¿puedes pegar la definición e inicialización de la variable `nombres`?

Comment: Y también la forma de llamar a la función problemática. Quiero decir... No únicamente la llamada sino también saber de donde sacas los dos valores que le pasas

Comment: ¿Podrías arreglar el formato del código y facilitarnos un escenario en el que podamos reproducir el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Llevo un rato mirando, pero creo que lo he encontrado:

```
num_nombres++;
} }

if (nombres != NULL){ *all_files = nombres; free_all_filenames_array(nombres,num_nombres); // AQUI ME SUELE DAR EL ERROR nombres = NULL; }else printf("Sin ficheros regulares");
```

Primero incrementas 'num_nombres', y luego llamas a 'free_all_filenames_array' con ese 'num_nombres' incrementado. No tengo un compilador a mano, pero intenta algo como

```
free_all_filenames_array( nombre, num_nombres - 1 );
```

Si estoy en lo cierto, estas intentando liberar memoria que tu no has asignado.

Comment: Gracias pero me sigue saliendo otro error de double free: 0x00007ffff7aa998e in malloc_printerr (action=1, 
    str=0x7ffff7b99718 "double free or corruption (fasttop)", exactamente en la linea 30, es decir en free(all_files).

Comment: Ese no es el problema. Si te fijas en el `realloc`, reserva `num_nombres+1`, luego esa llamada a `free_all_filenames_array` es, en teoría, correcta.

Answer (score 0):

El código que presentas tiene bastantes puntos conflictivos. Te enumero los que he podido localizar:

```
void free_all_filenames_array(char **all_files, int len){

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i<len; i++){

      if(all_files[i] != NULL){ // <<--- 1
       free(all_files[i]); // linea 24
       all_files[i] = NULL; // <<--- 2
      }
    }

  if(all_files != NULL){ // <<--- 3
  free(all_files);
  all_files = NULL; // <<--- 4
  }
}
```

1. Si a `free` se le pasa un puntero a `NULL` no hace absolutamente nada, luego esa comprobación te la puedes ahorrar sin miedo porque no te aporta nada de valor.
2. No tiene demasiado sentido que pongas el puntero a `NULL` cuando 4 líneas de código más abajo te vas a cargar esa zona de memoria. Esto no es conflictivo pero sí es una línea de código que no aporta absolutamente nada.
3. Esa comprobación o la borras o la mueves al principio de la función, ya que o bien asumes que siempre se va a llamar a la función pasando un puntero correcto o bien proteges la función desde el principio. Según lo comentado en el primer punto, esa comprobación tal cual está no tiene ninguna utilidad.
4. `all_files` es una variable local de la función... lo que hagas en dicha variable no se va a ver reflejado fuera luego o conviertes `all_files` en un puntero triple o te ahorras esta instrucción.

Más cosillas:

```
int read_all_filenames_array(char *path, char ***all_files, int *error){

  char **nombres = NULL;
  static int num_nombres = 0;
```

No tiene demasiado sentido que el contador de elementos en el arreglo se quede dentro de la función. Lo lógico es que el arreglo y el contador de elementos viajen juntos y lo ideal para esta situación es hacer uso de una estructura:

```
typedef struct
{
  char ** nombres;
  int num_nombres;
} ListaNombres;
```

¿Por qué es este un punto conflictivo? Porque para poder hacer algo con la lista de nombres fuera de la función necesitas saber cuántos elementos tiene la lista, por lo que tener cada valor por su lado complica el código final.

```
if(dir == NULL){
  printf(" ERROR");
  free(path); // <<--- 1
  *error = errno; // <<--- 2
  closedir(dir); // <<--- 3
  return -1;
}
```

1. Esta función no ha realizado la reserva de `path`, el nombre de la función no indica que la misma deba liberar la memoria y `path` es un puntero simple, luego después de la llamada a la función el puntero original queda desreferenciado y puede ser peligroso.
2. `errno` está disponible desde cualquier parte del código. Si se produce un error es mucho más legible optar por devolver un código de error fácilmente reconocible (el valor de un enumerado por ejemplo) o indicar simplemente que se ha producido un error y dejar que aquel que usa la función llame a `errno` por su cuenta.
3. Si no se ha podido abrir el fichero, el descriptor del mismo vale 0. Si intentas cerrar un descriptor con valor 0 la función no hace absolutamente nada... otra instrucción que sobra.

Más detallitos:

```
ptr = realloc(nombres, (num_nombres + 1) * sizeof(char *));
```

Teniendo en cuenta que `num_nombres` es estática, cada vez que llames a esta función intentará hacer una reserva cada vez más grande, lo cual no tiene sentido alguno porque la reserva que hiciste en la llamada anterior se ha perdido. A partir de la segunda llamada a la función el resultado devuelto será incorrecto.

```
if (nombres != NULL){
  *all_files = nombres;
 free_all_filenames_array(nombres,num_nombres); // AQUI ME SUELE DAR EL ERROR
 nombres = NULL;
}
```

Analicemos este código con tranquilidad:

- Si `nombres` no es `NULL` copias el puntero de `nombres` a `all_files`: Espero que en la documentación avises que la posible memoria apuntada inicialmente por `all_files` va a quedar desreferenciada ya que no va a ser posible recuperarla.
- Acto seguido liberas la memoria reservada por `nombres`, con lo que el puntero `all_files` queda automáticamente apuntando a una zona de memoria no válida.
- Pones `nombres` apuntando a `NULL`, lo cual no tiene ningún efecto porque `nombres` es una variable local.

Ese código deberías prácticamente reescribirlo entero porque tiene varios puntos conflictivos y peligrosos. Principalmente deberías centrarte en cuáles son las responsabilidades de la función y ceñirte a las mismas. Construir funciones monolíticas no suele ser una buena opción porque el código resultante suele ser complicado de gestionar.

Ah si, se me olvidaba... intenta tabular bien el código para poder diferenciar los bloques sin necesidad de tener que copiarlo en un editor de código y reindentarlo o tener que andar contando las llaves.

Un saludo.